# Filling an array with results of an async function

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, es6-promise

I need to set up an array of objects, however its attributes need to come from an async function.

For me to do this, I run `.map()` on the array, and do whatever it is I need to do on each element, but I need the result of the async function for them.

The way I am doing it right now I get `PromiseStatus` and `PromiseValue` as my result, which isn't what I want. I basically just want my `PromiseValue` in my array.

Here is my current code:

```
function processMyArray (array) {
  const processedArray = array.map(x => {
    return myAsyncFunction(x)
      .then((result) => {
        const { attribute1, attribute2 } = result
        return {
          attribute1,
          attribute2
        }
      })
  })
  return processedArray
}

// the rough code for myAsyncFunction()
 myAsyncFunction (data) {
    return Promise.all(
      [
        this.getAttribute1(data),
        this.getAttribute2(data)
      ]
    )
    .then(([attribute1, attribute2]) => {
      return {
        attribute1, attribute2
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Wrap the mapped into `Promise.all(array.map(...))`

Comment: @Jonasw, that was it! Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either wrap the mapped into

```
Promise.all(array.map(...))
```

or use cool ES 7 stuff ( await in for loops ):

```
async function processMyArray (array) {
  const result = [];
  for(const x of array){ //x is a bad name by the way
    const { attribute1, attribute2 } = await myAsyncFunction(x);
    result.push({ attribute1, attribute2 });
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: The key for me was knowing that `array.forEach` wont work, but I had to use a simple `for(x of array)`. Never realized that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this

```
const results = [];
await Promise.all(array.map(async (arrayElement, i) => {
    results[i] = await myAsyncFunction(arrayElement);
}));
```